# Procedimientos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que realizar un procedimiento de control de tiempos de una aplicación, desde que empieza hasta que termina y guardar dentro de este transcurso de la aplicación cuanto tiempo ha durado las distintas paradas.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Control_tiempos 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@lote nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @FechaInicioLote DATETIME
DECLARE @FechaFinLote DATETIME
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Calcular tiempo de parada por cada parada + motivo
-- Calcular tiempo de lote Fin - Inicio
SET @FechaInicioLote = (SELECT TOP 1 Inicio FROM _EBR_Parada WHERE Lote = @lote AND Inicio IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID ASC)
SET @FechaFinLote = (SELECT Fin FROM _EBR_Parada Where Lote = @lote AND Fin IS NOT NULL)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT * FROM _EBR_Parada WHERE Fin = @fin and Inicio = @inicio 

select * from [dbo].[_EBR_Control_TiemposBL3]
END
GO
insert into _EBR_Parada (EntreLotes, AccionLotes, Usuario)
            values (getDate(),'Limpieza Específica', 'Normon\gvargas')
```

Hasta aquí he podido llegar con los conocimientos que tengo, alguien con alguna experiencia en esto porfa

Comment: ¿Y cual sería tu duda o dificultad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes [la función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `DATEDIFF` que te permite obtener el tiempo transcurrido entre una fecha y otra.

En tu caso sería

`DECLARE @Segundos int = DATEDIFF(second, @FechaInicioLote, @FechaFinLote);`

En este caso medimos la diferencia de tiempo en segundos, aunque lo puedes contar con otra unidad de medida.

Comment: Gracias con eso me valdría